# re.findall only returning the last match

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;" colspan="1">10:10</td>
<td style="text-align: left;" colspan="1">This is a description.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">10:30</td>
<td colspan="1">This is another description.</td>
</tr>
```

I'm wanting to return multiple matches, each consisting of two groups: group 1 which is the timestamp, and group 2 which is the description.

When I run

```
re.findall(r'<td.*>(\d\d:\d\d)<\/td><td.*>(.*?)<\/td>', HTML)
```

I'm only getting the last match:

```
[('10:30', 'This is another description.')]
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my regex?

Comment: try with [^>]* instead of .*, you may be eating too many chars, esp. on the first .*

Comment: Why not parse it with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `.*` is matching as many characters as it can, so you get exactly one match that's everything from the first `<td` to the last `</td>`.  Using `[^>]*` instead of `.*` for the first two will make it only match what's inside one tag.